# Assign all panels and dialog boxes to appear on second display

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, osx

I have a MacBook Pro with a second display attached. When I work, I usually have the following setup:

- **MacBook display:** Messages and Chrome in split-screen mode (full-screen)
- **Second display:** Indesign/Illustrator/Photoshop (full-screen)

In the Dock on the second display I've right-clicked on my Adobe apps and clicked `Options > Assign to Desktop on Display 2`, which means that the apps open up on the second screen.

My problem is, however, that when I'm using one of these apps on my second display and I do something that brings up a dialog box (Save, Export etc) or a panel that isn't already open on the second display, it opens it in the background on my MacBook screen. It seems that, because I'm using split-screen (full-screen) mode on my MacBook, it brings the dialog box or panel up on a non-full-screen Space in the background.

Is there a way to have these dialog boxes and panels pop up on the application display/Space by default?

Comment: The only solution I know, is to make the second screen your `main display` in `System preferences > Displays > Arrangement...`: move the white bar at the top of one of the screens to the other screen.

Comment: Thanks @Joonas, I might try this. I wonder what happens when I disconnect the second display and reconnect it though - will it 'remember' that the second display is the primary one?

Comment: It will remember that.

Comment: @Joonas you should make that an answer :)